# TN-S Earthing parallel return paths when multiple MEN links

Tags: power-supply, protection, generator, circuit-protection

I have a bit-of a unique situation. I have a generator which is running a TN-S earthing system. It is powering demountable offices.

- I assume that all sub circuits would have RCDs in the demountable, I just didn't draw them in.

The earthing arrangement in the standards eludes to a parallel fault path when two MEN links are connected. In the picture below, I understand that this is not to standard, what I want to know is what is the parallel return path for a fault and why is it dangerous?

[image]

Can the system have multiple earth stakes with only one MEN link like this below?

[image]

Comment: From what I can see, you effectively have a TN-C system in the first picture, and TN-S in the second.

Comment: A TN-C system provides a PEN. It does not supply a Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first diagram shows a PME system, not TN-S as you have multiple E-N links. For a system to be TN-S there must be just a single link.

The issue is that in the event of a break in the N wire, return current will flow through the earth link.  This can cause significant voltage rises on earthed metal work if the earth link is not suitable sized, and cable overheating/fire risk, which can be an issue if it was not included in the design planning.

The second case is true TN-S.  The extra earthing is not an issue as it doesn't introduce an alternate N path.

For camping sites there are extensive regs on earthing, which you should read if you are setting up such a system. IIRC, PME is not allowed in such situations, as you can't reliably ensure equipotential bonding.

Comment: Oh yes, I see the parallel return path now, It will use the second MEN link to flow down the Earth. Fantastic thank you. I believe in this case everything is equipotential bonded.

Comment: I don't know which country you are in, but if in the UK, you should look at section 717 of the latest regs, which explicitly covers the risks and requirements for this kind of setup.  PME is explicitly called out as a risk, due to unreliable earthing and the use of demountable connections as part of the equipotential bonding.

Comment: You almost certainly need 30mA RCD on the supple side of each demountable connector.